# Join select statements and remove duplicates

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, distinct

I'm working with a SQL database, in which JobUID, jobcode, and UID should all have unique values.  I have an errant client which is creating duplicate entries where the JobUID and jobcode are duplicated, but the UID is still unique.

I'm running the same query against all of the views, in order to identify the duplicates.  It's a separate issue as to why there are duplicates, but I want to join these queries, so I get one table for my output, with no duplicates.

```
SELECT r.JobUID, r.jobcode, r.UID, count(1) 
from [dbo].FieldsView r 
group by r.JobUID, r.jobcode, r.UID 
having count(1) > 1 
order by 2, 3

SELECT r.JobUID, r.jobcode, r.UID, count(1)  
from [dbo].HistoryItemsView r  
group by r.JobUID, r.jobcode, r.UID  
having count(1) > 1  
order by 2, 3
```

When I change the query to this, I get just a list of affected Job codes, which is what I want:

```
SELECT Distinct r.jobcode, count(1)  
from [dbo].HistoryItemsView r  
group by r.JobUID, r.jobcode, r.UID  
having count(1) > 1

SELECT Distinct r.jobcode, count(1)  
from [dbo].FieldsView r  
group by r.JobUID, r.jobcode, r.UID  
having count(1) > 1
```

But now I want to join these, again removing duplicates, as the same jobcode will exist in each table, so I just get 1 table as output, with no duplicates.

Thanks

What I ended up using was this:

```
SELECT jobcode, SUM(Amount)
From (

SELECT r.JobUID, r.jobcode, r.UID, count(1) AS Amount 
from [dbo].FieldsView r 
group by r.JobUID, r.jobcode, r.UID having count(1) > 1 

UNION ALL

SELECT r.JobUID, r.jobcode, r.UID, count(1) AS Amount 
from [dbo].HistoryItemsView r 
group by r.JobUID, r.jobcode, r.UID having count(1) > 1 

) X
GROUP BY jobcode
Having SUM(Amount) > 1
```

thanks again!

Comment: Are you really sure that your two queries at the bottom return any results at all? Since r.UID is unique (according to your question), no grouping will take place and count(1) will always be 1, thus returning no rows at all. Similar example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0d723/7

Comment: It seemed to produce the same list job codes.  I ended up using the original queries and filtered for jobcode in the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO you are a bit unclear about the details.
If the combination of JobUID and jobcode should be unique over all views, then the following statement should do it:

```
SELECT JobUID, Jobcode, SUM(Amount)
FROM
(
    SELECT JobUID, Jobcode, COUNT(*) AS Amount
    from [dbo].HistoryItemsView r  
    group by r.JobUID, r.jobcode

    UNION ALL

    SELECT JobUID, Jobcode, COUNT(*)
    from [dbo].FieldsView r          
    group by r.JobUID, r.jobcode
) X
GROUP BY jobcode
HAVING SUM(Amount) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION` to get the non duplicated list. You then have to treat it as inner query to get the proper count.

```
SELECT jobcode, COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT Distinct r.jobcode  
    from [dbo].HistoryItemsView r  
    group by r.JobUID, r.jobcode, r.UID  
    having count(*) > 1

    UNION

    SELECT Distinct r.jobcode  
    from [dbo].FieldsView r  
    group by r.JobUID, r.jobcode, r.UID  
    having count(*) > 1
) X
GROUP BY jobcode
```